# Animating a hidden Div but preserving asp watermark extender

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, jquery-animate, watermark

I have a div that needs to be hidden and then shown via jQuery.

Within that div there is an asp textbox with an asp textbox watermark extender assigned to it.

If I leave the div shown everything works fine. However when I hide the div, upon show the watermark extender doesn't display until you click in and out of the textbox.

I've tried showing/hiding the div by:

- display: none;   and then shown via .fadeIn('slow');
- height: 0;       and then shown via .animate({ 'height': '200px' }, "slow");

In each case the watermark doesn't display on when the div appears.

Has anyone ever come across this issue before. Are there any other ways in jQuery that I could show/hide the div in order to get round this issue.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnFilter" runat="server" ImageUrl="mmmmmmmmmmmmm" OnClientClick="AnimateDivHeight('divFilter', 150)" />
<div id="divFilter" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlListsFilters" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">                                        

                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtListsFilterSearch" runat="server" CssClass="formfield" Width="220" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender id="tbweListsFilterSearch" runat="server" WatermarkCssClass="formfield-watermarked" WatermarkText="e.g. created by, tags, title" TargetControlID="txtListsFilterSearch" />&nbsp;&nbsp;

            </asp:Panel>
        </div>


function AnimateDivHeight(div, height) {
if ($('#' + div).height() == 0) {
    $("#" + div).animate({ 'height': height + 'px' }, "slow");
}
else {
    $("#" + div).animate({ 'height': '0px' }, "slow");
}
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us the markup and your code?

Comment: I've updated above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the hover() function?
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

I just made a submenu by HIDING the second div and showing it on hover. If you are trying to have it appear without hover, perhaps a onLoad event?

Here is what I did with my submenu if it helps...

```
$(document).ready(function () {             /* Function to create Sub Menus */


    var speed = 600;                                      //The Variable 'speed' is in milliseconds 
    $('li').hover(function () {               //Hover Function
                                  //Show its submenu            
   $(this).children('.nav2').stop().slideDown(speed);     
        },
        function () {
   $(this).children('.nav2').stop().hide(speed);
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't get round the issue of the watermark not displaying once the div is shown.